# Azure devops feed with PAT : what permissions are needed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We have a feed that we can correctly use from Visual Studio or Azure pipeline. 
Now, I want to use it from commandline (mainly for a dockerfile)

If I configure a PAT with "Build > Read" or "Build > Read & Execute" it does not work.
If I configure a PATH with "Full access", it works

My question is : what is the least privileged policy to use for the PAT in order to work with private nuget feed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need **read&write** permission in **Packing**. If the scopes does not show full , please click **Show all scopes** above the Save button.

[image]